# How to limit Number of simultaneous access to method by one user

Tags: java, spring

I have a project in which i need to give only 5 simultaneous request access to a method for one user.

For eg user 1: has sent  6 simultaneous requests to my method then my application must send him error that simultaneous request limit exceeded.

But at the same time system should not block simultaneous requests from more then one user

```
for example
user1 : sends 2 requests
user 2 sends : 4 requests
this should be accepted
```

This is my sample controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Response getSessionId(
            @PathParam("username") String username,
            @PathParam("password") String password) {


User user = checkAuth(username,password);

    response =  sendRequest.send; //I need to apply check on this call
}
```

Is it possible to do in any way.

I know we can throttle number of simultaneous requests but can we throttle number of simulatneous requests by different users

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a session variable which you would check and increase before each call to `sendRequest.send()`, and decrease after call.

```
//pseudo
int simultaneousRequests = session.get("simultaneousRequests") == null ? 0 : (int)session.get("simultaneousRequests");
if (simultaneousRequests >= 5) {
    throw SomeException();
}
session.put("simultaneousRequests", simultaneousRequests + 1);
response = sendRequest.send();
session.put("simultaneousRequests", simultaneousRequests - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a [j2ee filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) add that filter to the API calls where throttling is necessary. But you will need to send a unique identifier along with each HTTP request (probably a HTTP header) to identify each users to use this method.